# Google App Engine restrictions with java.io?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt

I have a GWT app, which runs fine locally with GAE Google App Engine.

Inside a serverside RPC service I use the following json class:
http://code.google.com/p/json-io/source/browse/src/main/java/com/cedarsoftware/util/io/JsonWriter.java

I works locally without problems, but when deploying to Google App Engine in the cloud, I'm getting a Stackoverflow right in this class.

May there be any limitations in the cloud that did not occur locally, and thus it fails? Or are any of the following classes not supported by google app engine in the cloud?

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.Closeable;
import java.io.Flushable;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.io.Writer;
```

This is the stacktrace I get in appengine logs:

```
javax.servlet.ServletContext log: Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call

java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponseForFailure(RPC.java:389)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:579)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:208)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:35)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.doFilter(JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.java:57)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:266)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:76)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:146)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:438)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:480)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:487)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:774)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$DoInTraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:751)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:342)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:334)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:484)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.io.PrintWriter.<init>(PrintWriter.java:116)
    at java.io.PrintWriter.<init>(PrintWriter.java:100)
    at java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format(SimpleFormatter.java:155)
    at java.util.logging.StreamHandler.publish(StreamHandler.java:196)
    at java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.publish(ConsoleHandler.java:105)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:530)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.doLog(Logger.java:551)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:640)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:30)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.util.io.JsonWriter.writeObject(JsonWriter.java:1508)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.util.io.JsonWriter.writeImpl(JsonWriter.java:636)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.util.io.JsonWriter.writeObject(JsonWriter.java:1531)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.util.io.JsonWriter.writeImpl(JsonWriter.java:636)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.util.io.JsonWriter.writeCollectionElement(JsonWriter.java:1441)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.util.io.JsonWriter.writeCollection(JsonWriter.java:980)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.util.io.JsonWriter.writeImpl(JsonWriter.java:608)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.util.io.JsonWriter.writeObject(JsonWriter.java:1531)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.util.io.JsonWriter.writeObject(JsonWriter.java:1531)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.util.io.JsonWriter.writeImpl(JsonWriter.java:636)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.util.io.JsonWriter.writeObject(JsonWriter.java:1531)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.util.io.JsonWriter.writeImpl(JsonWriter.java:636)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.util.io.JsonWriter.writeCollectionElement(JsonWriter.java:1441)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.util.io.JsonWriter.writeCollection(JsonWriter.java:980)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.util.io.JsonWriter.writeImpl(JsonWriter.java:608)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.util.io.JsonWriter.writeObject(JsonWriter.java:1531)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.util.io.JsonWriter.writeImpl(JsonWriter.java:636)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.util.io.JsonWriter.writeObject(JsonWriter.java:1531)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.util.io.JsonWriter.writeImpl(JsonWriter.java:636)
[and so on...]
```

Comment: You can check the white list classes here  https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/jrewhitelist

Comment: every used class it whitelisted, the problem has to be somewhere else. most likely an endless / too deep recursion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the recursive loop in local finishes because the stack size is big enough to resolve the operation, but in gae they are more restrictive.

A solution is to change your object complexity, is it possible that you post it here?

Comment: Hm no I cannot post it here, but maybe it is because I have some circular dependencies. Anyway, locally is works like a charm, which is really strange...

Comment: I've faced some problems of recursive calls which were fixed increasing the stack, but they were very edge cases. Normally when you get a loop like this the code is wrong, maybe no yours but the library you use. I would debug this loop in local to see if it's called a lot of times. Then investigate your classes, could be they have very nested attributes or something.

Comment: ok. how is it possible to increase the stack on the cloud GAE?

Comment: afaik it's not, maybe you can ask google support for it if you have a billed instance.

Comment: ok, no I don't have as it's just a pet project.